# Web View application not working properly on the Emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the Webview. We are using froyo 2.2 for development. and Eclipse 3.6. We have implemented the webview and It is working properly on mobile but when we are running on the Emulator it will give following error.

[image]

Can any one please tell why it is giving the error while it's run properly on mobile but on emulator above error is coming.

Comment: do you have an corporate proxy for connections to the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your internet premissions in you Android manifest ?

Comment: Yes I have set  : <uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>   and I have Internet connection also on my system.

Comment: @mayur rahatekar did you set the webviewClient() ?